# how can i remove extra space due to padding or margin from divs?

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue where each div gets expanded by the long text, but I would like to smaller than expanded since I need to place a matrix where it takes 16 columns , and having the current css it breaks the whole UI , but how can I fix this ? in my example it takes ~30% each side of padding or margin , and I want to fit the text with the div and if its a long text just add a newline on css

```
 <style>
        /* table board */
    .tabs.jsx-4167308660 {
    width: initial;
}

        .container {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
        }
        .col {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 10px 0 0;
            font-size: 11px;
        }
    
        .col .row {
            position: relative;
            margin: 10px 0 0 0;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #ebedee;
            /* height: 30px; */
            padding: 4px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    
        .col .row:first-child {
            background: #22244a;
            color: #fff;
        }
    
        .col .row:not(:first-child):after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            display: block;
            border-left: 10px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
            border-top: 10px solid #fc493e;
            z-index: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="jsx-4167308660 content">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">Reconnaissance</div>
            <div class="row"><span>Active Scanning</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Gather Victim Host Information</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Gather Victim Identity Information</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Gather Victim Network Information</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Gather Victim Org Information</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Phishing for Information</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Search Closed Sources</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Search Open Technical Databases</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Search Open Websites/Domains</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Search Victim-Owned Websites</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">Resource Development</div>
            <div class="row"><span>Acquire Infrastructure</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Compromise Accounts</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Compromise Infrastructure</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Develop Capabilities</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Establish Accounts</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Obtain Capabilities</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">Initial Access</div>
            <div class="row"><span>Drive-by Compromise</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Exploit Public-Facing Application</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>External Remote Services</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Drive-by Compromise</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Hardware Additions</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Exploit via Charging Station or PC</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Exploit via Radio Interfaces</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Install Insecure or Malicious Configuration</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Phishing</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Lockscreen Bypass</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Replication Through Removable Media</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Supply Chain Compromise</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Masquerade as Legitimate Application</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Trusted Relationship</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Valid Accounts</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Deliver Malicious App via Authorized App Store</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Deliver Malicious App via Other Means</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Supply Chain Compromise</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Data Historian Compromise</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Drive-by Compromise</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Engineering Workstation Compromise</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Exploit Public-Facing Application</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>External Remote Services</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Internet Accessible Device</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Replication Through Removable Media</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Spearphishing Attachment</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Supply Chain Compromise</span></div>
            <div class="row"><span>Wireless Compromise</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the content class? I would add that class to the css bc rn it seems like nothing is attached to that and I would set the margins on that to be position absolute or something along those lines

Comment: it just add `tabs.jsx-4167308660` where it takes `width: initial;` this is done by react, but I would like to remove that extra space

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understod you right. With these adjustments the content shouldnt break anymore

```css
body {margin:0}
.content {
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
        display: flex;
    }
    .col {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    .col + .col {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .col .row {
        position: relative;
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
        background: #ebedee;
        padding: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .col .row:first-child {
        background: #22244a;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .col .row:not(:first-child):after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        display: block;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
        border-top: 10px solid #fc493e;
        z-index: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="jsx-4167308660 content">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">Reconnaissance</div>
        <div class="row"><span>Active Scanning</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Gather Victim Host Information</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Gather Victim Identity Information</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Gather Victim Network Information</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Gather Victim Org Information</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Phishing for Information</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Search Closed Sources</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Search Open Technical Databases</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Search Open Websites/Domains</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Search Victim-Owned Websites</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">Resource Development</div>
        <div class="row"><span>Acquire Infrastructure</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Compromise Accounts</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Compromise Infrastructure</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Develop Capabilities</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Establish Accounts</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Obtain Capabilities</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">Initial Access</div>
        <div class="row"><span>Drive-by Compromise</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Exploit Public-Facing Application</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>External Remote Services</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Drive-by Compromise</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Hardware Additions</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Exploit via Charging Station or PC</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Exploit via Radio Interfaces</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Install Insecure or Malicious Configuration</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Phishing</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Lockscreen Bypass</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Replication Through Removable Media</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Supply Chain Compromise</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Masquerade as Legitimate Application</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Trusted Relationship</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Valid Accounts</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Deliver Malicious App via Authorized App Store</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Deliver Malicious App via Other Means</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Supply Chain Compromise</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Data Historian Compromise</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Drive-by Compromise</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Engineering Workstation Compromise</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Exploit Public-Facing Application</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>External Remote Services</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Internet Accessible Device</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Replication Through Removable Media</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Spearphishing Attachment</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Supply Chain Compromise</span></div>
        <div class="row"><span>Wireless Compromise</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific width for your `.col` - give it the width! I added in the fiddle below. To give it's text the possibility to wrap, give the `.row` a `white-space: wrap;`

There is no class `.container` in your HTML-Sample but a `class="content"`.
I think you should use this guide for `display: flex;`:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

And try yourself https://jsfiddle.net/18qjy367/2/

Comment: how does it will remove extra margin, since I want to keep the same format when shrink and avoid divs large than others ?

Comment: there is no extra margin. The `.row` is a `<div>` and they have standard `display: block;` what gives them `width: 100%;` of the parent element's width. So if your `.col` is about 30% width, your `.row` will have the same width. Try give the `.row` a `display: inline-block` like here: [https://jsfiddle.net/txdf732k/](https://jsfiddle.net/txdf732k/)